# Magento 2 : Extend graphql schema

Tags: magento2, graphql

i have override "revokeCustomerToken" mutation & tried to add input "page data" to it, but it seems "revokeCustomerToken" does not support input attributes

```
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/revoke-customer-token.html.
```

Is their any way we can pass some data in "revokeCustomerToken" mutation ?

like

```
mutation {
  revokeCustomerToken {
    result
    pagedata
  }
}
```

**I doubt it does not support input parameters.**

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what code you did till now. But I can suggest you the way to achieve your requirements.

You need to create one custom module in order to overwrite this mutation. In your custom module you need to create schema file named as "**schema.graphqls**" under etc folder.

In this file you can write like below:

```
type RevokeCustomerTokenOutput {
    pagedata:PageData @resolver (class: "\\Hello\\World\\Model\\Resolver\\Customer\\PageDataResolver") @doc(description:"Pagedata for respective customer.")    
}
```

Further, you need to create **PageDataResolver.php** at specified path to return the relevant data.

I hope this helps you. Let me know if you have any query further.

Happy to help always!

Comment: Hello pratik, i am not much sure if there will be another resolver for pagedata input, i guess there should be only one resolver for one mutation.

Comment: pagedata: {
  location: "test"
  login_type: "test"
  page_path: "test@example.com"
  page_referrer: "test"
  page_title: "test"
  page_url: "test"
}

this is i would like to pass with page data is that possible with this ?
Thanks for the reply

Comment: I got this error - (GraphQL\Error\Error): Type "PageData" not found in document.

Comment: If you don't want to create another resolver for pagedata then you can use the one which is defined by magento for result. Then you need to overwrite that resolver in order to access the pagedata field and write your business logic.

Comment: Thanks, can you please advise me about the schema so i can run it in chrome graphql tool and check if its working ?
I had tried with below

mutation {
      revokeCustomerToken (
        result: "true"
        pagedata {
      page_path : 'login'
     }
      )
    }

Comment: Does it work for you @pratik ?